# Отлов сигнала от QlineEdit() PyQt5?

Tags: python, pyqt5, qt-designer

Отлов сигнала от QlineEdit() PyQt5?
День добрый.
Деплою GUI Приложение на платформе Python с графическим модулем PyQt5.
Откомпилировал приложение в Qt Design.
После отображаются два файла main.py and mydes.py.
Не могу отловить значение получаеммое методом.
text = self.EnterText.text()
Print(text)
Код предоставлю на repl с возможностью редактировать и далее ниже по тексту.
MAIN.py

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
from mydes import Ui_Form  # импорт нашего сгенерированного файла
from PyQt5.QtCore import pyqtSignal, QObject
import sys

class mywindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(mywindow, self).__init__()
        super().__init__()
        self.ui = Ui_Form()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)

        self.ui.BUTTONpush.clicked.connect(self.btnClicked)
        text = self.ui.EnterText.text()

    def btnClicked(self):
        #self.ui.label.setText("Вы нажали на кнопку!")
        # Если не использовать, то часть текста исчезнет.
        #self.ui.label.adjustSize()
        print('Нажали на кнопку' )
        print(text, 'введеный текс')

    def mostrarFuncion(self):
        minombre = self.EnterText.text()
        micontrasena = self.contrasena.text()
        print("Nombre: " +minombre + " Contrasena: ")
        self.setWindowTitle("Nombre: " +minombre + " Contrasena:")

app = QtWidgets.QApplication([])
application = mywindow()
application.show()

sys.exit(app.exec())
```

mydes.py

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

# Form implementation generated from reading ui file '1.ui'
#
# Created by: PyQt5 UI code generator 5.13.2
#
# WARNING! All changes made in this file will be lost!


from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class Ui_Form(object):
    def setupUi(self, Form):
        Form.setObjectName("Form")
        Form.setWindowModality(QtCore.Qt.NonModal)
        Form.setEnabled(True)
        Form.resize(342, 380)
        Form.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(342, 380))
        Form.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(342, 380))
        self.BUTTONpush = QtWidgets.QPushButton(Form)
        self.BUTTONpush.setEnabled(True)
        self.BUTTONpush.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 350, 341, 31))
        self.BUTTONpush.setObjectName("BUTTONpush")
        self.scrollArea = QtWidgets.QScrollArea(Form)
        self.scrollArea.setEnabled(True)
        self.scrollArea.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 120, 341, 191))
        self.scrollArea.setWidgetResizable(True)
        self.scrollArea.setObjectName("scrollArea")
        self.scrollAreaWidgetContents = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.scrollAreaWidgetContents.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 339, 189))
        self.scrollAreaWidgetContents.setObjectName("scrollAreaWidgetContents")
        self.listView = QtWidgets.QListView(self.scrollAreaWidgetContents)
        self.listView.setEnabled(True)
        self.listView.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 341, 191))
        self.listView.setObjectName("listView")
        self.scrollArea.setWidget(self.scrollAreaWidgetContents)

        self.EnterText = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(Form)
        self.EnterText.setEnabled(True)
        self.EnterText.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 310, 341, 41))
        self.EnterText.setObjectName("EnterText")
        minombre = self.EnterText.text()
        print(minombre)

        self.textEdit = QtWidgets.QTextEdit(Form)
        self.textEdit.setEnabled(False)
        self.textEdit.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 341, 31))
        self.textEdit.setObjectName("textEdit")
        self.ProxyInput = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(Form)
        self.ProxyInput.setEnabled(True)
        self.ProxyInput.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(60, -1, 281, 31))
        self.ProxyInput.setObjectName("ProxyInput")
        self.textEdit_2 = QtWidgets.QTextEdit(Form)
        self.textEdit_2.setEnabled(False)
        self.textEdit_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 30, 341, 31))
        self.textEdit_2.setObjectName("textEdit_2")
        self.PortInput = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(Form)
        self.PortInput.setEnabled(True)
        self.PortInput.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(60, 30, 281, 31))
        self.PortInput.setObjectName("PortInput")
        self.textEdit_3 = QtWidgets.QTextEdit(Form)
        self.textEdit_3.setEnabled(False)
        self.textEdit_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 60, 341, 31))
        self.textEdit_3.setObjectName("textEdit_3")
        self.TokenInput = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(Form)
        self.TokenInput.setEnabled(True)
        self.TokenInput.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(60, 60, 281, 31))
        self.TokenInput.setObjectName("TokenInput")
        self.textEdit_4 = QtWidgets.QTextEdit(Form)
        self.textEdit_4.setEnabled(False)
        self.textEdit_4.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 90, 341, 31))
        self.textEdit_4.setObjectName("textEdit_4")
        self.ChatInput = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(Form)
        self.ChatInput.setEnabled(True)
        self.ChatInput.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(60, 90, 281, 31))
        self.ChatInput.setObjectName("ChatInput")

        self.retranslateUi(Form)
        self.BUTTONpush.clicked.connect(self.EnterText.clear)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Form)

    def retranslateUi(self, Form):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        Form.setWindowTitle(_translate("Form", "Chat telegram"))
        Form.setToolTip(_translate("Form", "<html><head/><body><p>vd</p></body></html>"))
        self.BUTTONpush.setText(_translate("Form", "Send Message"))
        self.EnterText.setText(_translate("Form", "text"))
        self.textEdit.setHtml(_translate("Form", "<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC \"-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0//EN\" \"http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/strict.dtd\">\n"
"<html><head><meta name=\"qrichtext\" content=\"1\" /><style type=\"text/css\">\n"
"p, li { white-space: pre-wrap; }\n"
"</style></head><body style=\" font-family:\'MS Shell Dlg 2\'; font-size:8.25pt; font-weight:400; font-style:normal;\">\n"
"<p style=\" margin-top:0px; margin-bottom:0px; margin-left:0px; margin-right:0px; -qt-block-indent:0; text-indent:0px;\"><span style=\" font-family:\'MS Shell Dlg 2\';\">Proxy</span></p></body></html>"))
        self.textEdit_2.setHtml(_translate("Form", "<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC \"-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0//EN\" \"http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/strict.dtd\">\n"
"<html><head><meta name=\"qrichtext\" content=\"1\" /><style type=\"text/css\">\n"
"p, li { white-space: pre-wrap; }\n"
"</style></head><body style=\" font-family:\'MS Shell Dlg 2\'; font-size:8.25pt; font-weight:400; font-style:normal;\">\n"
"<p style=\" margin-top:0px; margin-bottom:0px; margin-left:0px; margin-right:0px; -qt-block-indent:0; text-indent:0px;\"><span style=\" font-family:\'MS Shell Dlg 2\';\">Port</span></p></body></html>"))
        self.textEdit_3.setHtml(_translate("Form", "<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC \"-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0//EN\" \"http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/strict.dtd\">\n"
"<html><head><meta name=\"qrichtext\" content=\"1\" /><style type=\"text/css\">\n"
"p, li { white-space: pre-wrap; }\n"
"</style></head><body style=\" font-family:\'MS Shell Dlg 2\'; font-size:8.25pt; font-weight:400; font-style:normal;\">\n"
"<p style=\" margin-top:0px; margin-bottom:0px; margin-left:0px; margin-right:0px; -qt-block-indent:0; text-indent:0px;\"><span style=\" font-family:\'MS Shell Dlg 2\';\">token</span></p></body></html>"))
        self.textEdit_4.setHtml(_translate("Form", "<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC \"-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0//EN\" \"http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/strict.dtd\">\n"
"<html><head><meta name=\"qrichtext\" content=\"1\" /><style type=\"text/css\">\n"
"p, li { white-space: pre-wrap; }\n"
"</style></head><body style=\" font-family:\'MS Shell Dlg 2\'; font-size:8.25pt; font-weight:400; font-style:normal;\">\n"
"<p style=\" margin-top:0px; margin-bottom:0px; margin-left:0px; margin-right:0px; -qt-block-indent:0; text-indent:0px;\"><span style=\" font-family:\'MS Shell Dlg 2\';\">chat_id</span></p></body></html>"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Переменная text уничтожается сразу при выходе за пределы конструктора.

Лучше так:

```py
def btnClicked(self):
    #self.ui.label.setText("Вы нажали на кнопку!")
    # Если не использовать, то часть текста исчезнет.
    #self.ui.label.adjustSize()
    print('Нажали на кнопку' )
    print(self.ui.EnterText.text(), 'введеный текст')
```

Answer (score 0):

Как вариант. Я отметил для вас строки, в которые внес изменения.

Обратите внимание на строку:

```
#???        self.BUTTONpush.clicked.connect(self.EnterText.clear)          # ---
```

---

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtCore import pyqtSignal, QObject

#from mydes import Ui_Form  # импорт нашего сгенерированного файла
class Ui_Form(object):
    def setupUi(self, Form):
        Form.setObjectName("Form")
        Form.setWindowModality(QtCore.Qt.NonModal)
        Form.setEnabled(True)
        Form.resize(342, 380)
        Form.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(342, 380))
        Form.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(342, 380))
        self.BUTTONpush = QtWidgets.QPushButton(Form)
        self.BUTTONpush.setEnabled(True)
        self.BUTTONpush.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 350, 341, 31))
        self.BUTTONpush.setObjectName("BUTTONpush")
        self.scrollArea = QtWidgets.QScrollArea(Form)
        self.scrollArea.setEnabled(True)
        self.scrollArea.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 120, 341, 191))
        self.scrollArea.setWidgetResizable(True)
        self.scrollArea.setObjectName("scrollArea")
        self.scrollAreaWidgetContents = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.scrollAreaWidgetContents.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 339, 189))
        self.scrollAreaWidgetContents.setObjectName("scrollAreaWidgetContents")
        self.listView = QtWidgets.QListView(self.scrollAreaWidgetContents)
        self.listView.setEnabled(True)
        self.listView.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 341, 191))
        self.listView.setObjectName("listView")
        self.scrollArea.setWidget(self.scrollAreaWidgetContents)

        self.EnterText = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(Form)
        self.EnterText.setEnabled(True)
        self.EnterText.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 310, 341, 41))
        self.EnterText.setObjectName("EnterText")
        minombre = self.EnterText.text()
        print(minombre)

        self.textEdit = QtWidgets.QTextEdit(Form)
        self.textEdit.setEnabled(False)
        self.textEdit.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 341, 31))
        self.textEdit.setObjectName("textEdit")
        self.ProxyInput = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(Form)
        self.ProxyInput.setEnabled(True)
        self.ProxyInput.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(60, -1, 281, 31))
        self.ProxyInput.setObjectName("ProxyInput")
        self.textEdit_2 = QtWidgets.QTextEdit(Form)
        self.textEdit_2.setEnabled(False)
        self.textEdit_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 30, 341, 31))
        self.textEdit_2.setObjectName("textEdit_2")
        self.PortInput = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(Form)
        self.PortInput.setEnabled(True)
        self.PortInput.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(60, 30, 281, 31))
        self.PortInput.setObjectName("PortInput")
        self.textEdit_3 = QtWidgets.QTextEdit(Form)
        self.textEdit_3.setEnabled(False)
        self.textEdit_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 60, 341, 31))
        self.textEdit_3.setObjectName("textEdit_3")
        self.TokenInput = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(Form)
        self.TokenInput.setEnabled(True)
        self.TokenInput.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(60, 60, 281, 31))
        self.TokenInput.setObjectName("TokenInput")
        self.textEdit_4 = QtWidgets.QTextEdit(Form)
        self.textEdit_4.setEnabled(False)
        self.textEdit_4.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 90, 341, 31))
        self.textEdit_4.setObjectName("textEdit_4")
        self.ChatInput = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(Form)
        self.ChatInput.setEnabled(True)
        self.ChatInput.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(60, 90, 281, 31))
        self.ChatInput.setObjectName("ChatInput")

        self.retranslateUi(Form)

#???        self.BUTTONpush.clicked.connect(self.EnterText.clear)                       # ---

        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Form)

    def retranslateUi(self, Form):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        Form.setWindowTitle(_translate("Form", "Chat telegram"))
        Form.setToolTip(_translate("Form", "<html><head/><body><p>vd</p></body></html>"))
        self.BUTTONpush.setText(_translate("Form", "Send Message"))
        self.EnterText.setText(_translate("Form", "text"))
        self.textEdit.setHtml(_translate("Form", "<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC \"-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0//EN\" \"http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/strict.dtd\">\n"
"<html><head><meta name=\"qrichtext\" content=\"1\" /><style type=\"text/css\">\n"
"p, li { white-space: pre-wrap; }\n"
"</style></head><body style=\" font-family:\'MS Shell Dlg 2\'; font-size:8.25pt; font-weight:400; font-style:normal;\">\n"
"<p style=\" margin-top:0px; margin-bottom:0px; margin-left:0px; margin-right:0px; -qt-block-indent:0; text-indent:0px;\"><span style=\" font-family:\'MS Shell Dlg 2\';\">Proxy</span></p></body></html>"))
        self.textEdit_2.setHtml(_translate("Form", "<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC \"-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0//EN\" \"http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/strict.dtd\">\n"
"<html><head><meta name=\"qrichtext\" content=\"1\" /><style type=\"text/css\">\n"
"p, li { white-space: pre-wrap; }\n"
"</style></head><body style=\" font-family:\'MS Shell Dlg 2\'; font-size:8.25pt; font-weight:400; font-style:normal;\">\n"
"<p style=\" margin-top:0px; margin-bottom:0px; margin-left:0px; margin-right:0px; -qt-block-indent:0; text-indent:0px;\"><span style=\" font-family:\'MS Shell Dlg 2\';\">Port</span></p></body></html>"))
        self.textEdit_3.setHtml(_translate("Form", "<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC \"-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0//EN\" \"http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/strict.dtd\">\n"
"<html><head><meta name=\"qrichtext\" content=\"1\" /><style type=\"text/css\">\n"
"p, li { white-space: pre-wrap; }\n"
"</style></head><body style=\" font-family:\'MS Shell Dlg 2\'; font-size:8.25pt; font-weight:400; font-style:normal;\">\n"
"<p style=\" margin-top:0px; margin-bottom:0px; margin-left:0px; margin-right:0px; -qt-block-indent:0; text-indent:0px;\"><span style=\" font-family:\'MS Shell Dlg 2\';\">token</span></p></body></html>"))
        self.textEdit_4.setHtml(_translate("Form", "<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC \"-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0//EN\" \"http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/strict.dtd\">\n"
"<html><head><meta name=\"qrichtext\" content=\"1\" /><style type=\"text/css\">\n"
"p, li { white-space: pre-wrap; }\n"
"</style></head><body style=\" font-family:\'MS Shell Dlg 2\'; font-size:8.25pt; font-weight:400; font-style:normal;\">\n"
"<p style=\" margin-top:0px; margin-bottom:0px; margin-left:0px; margin-right:0px; -qt-block-indent:0; text-indent:0px;\"><span style=\" font-family:\'MS Shell Dlg 2\';\">chat_id</span></p></body></html>"))


class mywindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(mywindow, self).__init__()
        super().__init__()
        self.ui = Ui_Form()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)

        self.ui.BUTTONpush.clicked.connect(self.btnClicked)

        self.ui.EnterText.textChanged.connect(self.text_changed)                          # +++
        self.text = self.ui.EnterText.text()

    def text_changed(self, text):                                                         # +++
        self.text = text

    def btnClicked(self):
        #self.ui.label.setText("Вы нажали на кнопку!")
        # Если не использовать, то часть текста исчезнет.
        #self.ui.label.adjustSize()


        print('Нажали на кнопку' )
        print(f'`{self.text}` <--- введеный текс')

    def mostrarFuncion(self):
        minombre = self.EnterText.text()
        micontrasena = self.contrasena.text()
        print("Nombre: " +minombre + " Contrasena: ")
        self.setWindowTitle("Nombre: " +minombre + " Contrasena:")

app = QtWidgets.QApplication([])
application = mywindow()
application.show()

sys.exit(app.exec())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Да добавляя решетки и коментируя строку.
"Отчистить поле после нажатия на Кнопку-Bytton"
Текс держится в переменной, и при этом отображается в консоли лога.
СТоит задача отчищать данный блок по нажатию кнопки...

Comment: @N.Zarchi добавьте строку `self.ui.EnterText.clear()`  после `print(f'{self.text} <--- введеный текс')`

Comment: self.ui.ProxyInput.textChanged.connect(self.text_proxy)                          # +++
        self.proxy = self.ui.ProxyInput.text()
    def text_proxy(self, text):                                                         # +++
        self.proxy = text
        print(self.proxy) 

        self.ui.PortInput.textChanged.connect(self.text_port)                          # +++
        self.port = self.ui.PortInput.text()
    def text_port(self, text):                                                         # +++
        self.port = text
        print(self.port)

Comment: Ставлю такой код для первых четырех значений. Для прокси срабатывает и отображается лог для порта уже не срабатывает.

Comment: self.ui.EnterText.clear() после print(f'{self.text} <--- введеный текс')//
Отчистится ЛОГ консоли. А не Окно ввода текста в GUI формате.
#???        self.BUTTONpush.clicked.connect(self.EnterText.clear)          # ---
в Qt designer Эта строка чистит эту форму. Но тогда не отображается ЛОГ.

Comment: @N.Zarchi sorry, объясните пожалуйста лучше (словами по шагам), что вы хотите сделать.

Comment: Добавить соксы, и по нажатию на пуш отправить сообщение.
В блок который по середине Qwiev выводить сообщения получаемые и отправляемые от chat_id И token.

Comment: @https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1122946/Не-работает-переменная-в-qt-designer-python3-с-соксами